# R Markdown - How table generated data be formatted better?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have an R Markdown file that shows the results of a study I'm doing. The output, in part, looks as follows, below. You can see that the generated HTML isn't doing a very good job of formatting the table. It appears all this data could easily fit as one table, and not be split into two.  Is there anyway I can get R Markdown to format this better?

[image]

If it helps, the following is the R Markdown code that generates this data.

````
```{r}
tbl = table(gssData$denom, gssData$attend)

results <- chisq.test(tbl)
results$expected

```
````

Comment: increase the `options(width = 80)`

Comment: `?knitr::kable()` || `?DT::datatable`. There are a few (more than a few, really) other options, but `kable()` may fit your needs.

Comment: @rawr - That worked for me. If you want to create an answer, I'll accept it.